# How to get quarterly average through DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

I have data like below, I want to calculate Quarterly average through Dax. could someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IF(
  HASONEVALUE('Table'[Quarter]),
  CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Sales]), ALL('Table'), VALUES('Table'[Quarter])))
```

If the filter context allows Quarter to have more than one distinct value, this is BLANK().
Otherwise, all parts of the filter context other than the quarter are removed, and the average is taken of the sales.

This could require some changes, depending on how you want to handle multiple years worth of data, and incomplete months/quarters.

Comment: Here my "sales" is calculated measure

Comment: @sumantthpendemssai: Replace `AVERAGE('Table'[Sales])` with `AVERAGEX(VALUES('Table'[Month]), [Sales])` in that case.